# How to append row properly together with number by using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is my code in HTML:

```
<table width="600px" id="project">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><textarea name="pro_1" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><textarea name="pro_2" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><textarea name="pro_3" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td><textarea name="pro_4" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td><textarea name="pro_5" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input id="addbtn" type="button" name="addbtn" value="ADD">
```

This is my Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addbtn").click(function()
        $("table#project,textarea").append("<tr><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr>").attr({cols:"100",rows:"2"});
    }); 
});
```

Actually there are two issues when I coding:
First,when I first click on the button,it will append the row but didn't fit to the size of  where conform to "attr" in Jquery Code.But it will work when I second click on the button.
Second,it didn't append the number with  in the code.

Comment: You won't be able to set the `td` attribute that way. you're appending a string rather than a jQuery object.

Comment: Are you appending an entire table row to a textarea? I was expecting that you would want to append it to the table instead.

Comment: Not，it just appending the row only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addbtn").click(function()
        $("table#project").append('<tr><td>6</td><td><textarea cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td></tr>');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: To do so,how I going to append entire row together with the numbering when I click the button?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which number in the code you're referring to; in the code you've provided you just have a hard-coded 6.

There's also some confusion about how your code actually works and how I believe you think it works.

The first part, the selector, looks like this:

```
$("table#project,textarea")
```

That's pretty straightforward. It selects the table with the ID `project` and also selects all `<textarea>` elements.

The next part, the append, looks like this:

```
.append("<tr><td>6</td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr>")
```

Also pretty straightforward. It will (attempt to) append that HTML to all of the matched elements - the `<table>` and all of the `<textarea>` elements - but only add it to the table since a `<textarea>` doesn't have child elements.

The final part:

```
.attr({cols:"100",rows:"2"});
```

sets those attributes on all of the matched elements. That's the `<table>` element as well as all but the last of the `<textarea>` elements. Why all but the last? Because the `.append()` function doesn't update the set of matched elements in the jQuery object - you're still working with those that were selected when you executed your selector, which happened *before* the `.append()` to add the last one.

I'd suggest the following instead:

```
$('#project').append('<tr><td>' + yourNumberVariable + '</td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr>').find('textarea').attr({cols: "100", rows: "2"});
```

That appends the new row to the `<table>` (the selector uses an ID so there's probably no reason to include the tag name, but add it back in if you wish or do actually need to), then finds all `<textarea>` elements (including the one just added), then sets the attributes on those.

Comment: OMG,I really sorry about my big mistake,the hard-code 6 I putted in side just for testing.If this one is eliminated,how does this appended when I click on the button?Thank.

Comment: @JCChan I've suggested some code to do it at the end of my answer. The same principle applies, you'll just need to modify the HTML string to use the variable containing the correct number.

Comment: Anthony Grist Another one important thing,how to get the NumberVariable?It's actually a dynamic function and will generate the number automatically when the button is clicked.

Comment: @JCChan Can you update the question to include the code you've currently got for that?

Comment: I use this method:<$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#addbtn").click(function(){
    var num=parseInt($("#project tr:last").text());
 num+=1;
 $("#project,textarea").append("<tr><td>"+num+"</td><td><textarea cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
 });
});>

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, your selector `$("table#project,textarea")` is asking for a `table` called 'project' OR any `textarea`s.  It's then inserting a bunch of html after whatever that selects, and trying to set some attributes on it, but the html you've got is a table row with a cell in it, etc. so the outer most element of that is the `tr` (i.e. the table row) and you're setting the `cols` and `rows` attributes of that, not the `textarea` as I'm assuming you want.

What you probably want is something like:

```
$("table#project").append("<tr><td>6</td><td><textarea cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#project tr:last').after('<tr><td>6</td><td><textarea cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: If you're going to select the last `<tr>` element then you want to use `.after()`, not `.append()`. Using `.append()` would try to add the new `<tr>` to the content of an existing one (which isn't valid, but the browser might fix it for you). There's really no need to change the selector or the function used though.

Answer (score 0):

Just short and simple do this in append:

```
$("table#project,textarea").append(
       "<tr><td>6</td><td><textarea cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#addbtn").click(function(){
    var num = parseInt($("tr:last").text());
    num += 1;
    var row = $("<tr><td>"+num+"</td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr>");
 $("table#project").append(row).find('textarea').attr({cols:"100",rows:"2"});
});
```

This will let you *number row automatically* and plus appends rows with desired attrs. I assumed you might not want to number new row to *6 only*. So I added logic for numbering also.

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2g9dR/)

Comment: Sorry guys,I just make a amendment about hard-code 6 in-between <td></td> inside the <tr>.Sorry for bewildered.

Comment: Thank you so much.I just a beginner for Jquery,it was great honour received a lot of favor comment and instruction.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that get from you all suggestion:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#addbtn").click(function(){
  var num=parseInt($("#project tr:last").text());
num+=1;
$("#project,textarea").append("<tr><td>"+num+"</td><td><textarea cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
});
  });
```

Comment: How about if I did it with multiple table?I'd try but when the button is clicked will shown that the number will continue or append wherever button is clicked with different table.For instance,when you click the button on table1 is display number 5,subsequently click the button on table2,it will display number 6.